# TypeError: CanvasRenderService is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js, chart.js

MY corona bot was working for a long time. it was offline for 3 months. Now, i have hosted it in vultr (hosting service). But i never faced this error, but facing this now....

New:

I just had a look, still i am having new error. **MY code**: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/16c003ce7e49471b9fc7f4af25a688ae

Error is:
`5|x | (node:19549) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An options parameter object is required –`

Yes i have moved from `CanvasRenderService` to `ChartJSNodeCanvas`

Old:

```
 const { CanvasRenderSerice } = require("chartjs-node-canvas")
 
       const canvasRenderService = new CanvasRenderService(
           width,
           height,
           ChartJS => {}
        );
```

With error:

```
5|x | (node:18303) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: CanvasRenderService is not a constructor
5|x |     at Client.<anonymous> (/root/covid/bot.js:357:37)
5|x |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have renamed their service from `CanvasRenderSerice` in version **2.x.x** to `ChartJSNodeCanvas` in version **3.x.x**.

So you might be using version **3.x.x**. Either downgrade your `chartjs-node-canvas` version **2.x.x** or update your code according to new version.

2.x.x syntax

```
CanvasRenderService(width, height, chartCallback, type, chartJsFactory)
```

3.x.x

```
ChartJSNodeCanvas(options)
```

so in new version you've to use like

```
new ChartJSNodeCanvas({ width, height })
```

```js
const { ChartJSNodeCanvas } = require('chartjs-node-canvas');
 
const chartCallback = (ChartJS) => {
    // Global config example: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/
    ChartJS.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.borderWidth = 2;
};
 
const canvasRenderService = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({ width, height, chartCallback});

(async () => {
  const configuration = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: dates,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Total Cases",
          data: cases,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,0,0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,255,0,1)",
          borderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: 2
        },

        {
          label: "Recoveries",
          data: recovered,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
          borderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: 2
        },
        {
          label: "Deaths",
          data: deaths,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.1)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
          borderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: 2
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
          fontColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255,1)",
          fontSize: 16
        }
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: {
          grid: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            fontColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1"
          }
        },
        yAxes: {
          grid: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"
          },
          ticks: {
            fontColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
})
const image = await canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer( configuration );
```

Comment: I just had a look, still i am having new error.

MY code: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/16c003ce7e49471b9fc7f4af25a688ae

Error is: 5|x | (node:19549) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An options parameter object is required

Comment: Seems you just tried by renaming service. There is a change in constructor params as well. updated answer with new syntax.

Comment: Though, any idea about this? the fonts are broken too 
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/692068114694668378/831764878359265330/Corona_Support_all_Graph.png

Comment: Like I said earlier, from 2.x to 3.x it's has many more breaking changes. Please check [3.x Migration Guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html) for detailed information. Just updated my answer with basic changes code snippet, you can check that.

Comment: Thanks :)  i just registered the font arialbd seems to be fine now.

Comment: If you are not familiar with all those migration changes, I would suggest you to downgrade your version to 2.x.x.

Comment: I have one more question. writing it dont go haha

Comment: I have logged by deaths which is an array of deaths of last 10 days of a country. But when i console log it looks fine. but in my chart it is always in 0. can you check my configuration in the paste.gg link? and correct my faults ;(

Comment: not pretty sure what is issue, it would be easy to understand the issue at least if you can post the sample data as well as how it's looking in chart.

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/692067674083033147/831806298805764126/Corona_Support_bd_Graph.png

sample data

Comment: Sample data? Remember to share minimal reproducible information(site link, executable example, etc.) otherwise it's hard to understand the exact issue.

Comment: **Its in a discord server, do you have discord? ** please come here,being hard to talk here:  https://discord.gg/6CgTj8e